# How to apply some function to each line of file in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a `parseMessage` function, and I want it to apply to every line of file and get array of results. How can I do that?

```
parseMessage :: String -> SpecificDataStructure

type Path = String
parseFile :: Path -> [SpecificDataStructure]
parseFile what_do_I_need_here?
```

Answer (score 5):

First, you have to recognize that `parseFile` has to operate in the IO monad, since it involves file I/O. This means extracting the contents from the IO action produced by `readFile`, then packaging the results back into an IO action. Here it is first in two steps, separating the pure computation from the IO actions:

```
parseContents :: String -> [SpecificDataStructure]
parseContents contents = map parseMessage (lines contents)

parseFile :: String -> IO [SpecificDataStructure]
parseFile fileName = readFile fileName >>= return . parseContents
```

and here it is written as one function

```
parseFile :: String -> IO [SpecificDataStructure]
parseFile fileName = do
                   contents <- readFile fileName
                   let parsed = map parseMessage (lines contents)
                   return parsed
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking to do something like this:

```
parseFile = do
    f <- readFile "myfile.txt"
    map myFunc $ lines f
```

`lines` splits a file into a list of `String`s, and `map` lets you apply a function (supplied in the first argument) to each element of the list. The result is a list of values. (`:t map` in GHCi yields `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`).

Answer (score 0):

First, get the contents of the file using readFile

```
contents <- readFile "filename"
```

Then, split the file into lines using the function appropriately named function

```
let fileLines = lines contents
```

Finally, convert each line to your structure

```
let objects = map parseMessage fileLines
```

This will be an array of structures representing the original file.